# pandas bar chart: use aggregated output as x-axis and colors for each group

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, bar-chart, aggregate-functions

I have the following code, the `result` column has values `Won` or `Lost`:

```
 df.groupby('result')['col_A'].agg(['mean','median']).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

How do I make the x-axis be mean & median, and use the color for the Won/Lost group? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just transpose the dataframe before the plotting:

```
df.groupby('result')['col_A'].agg(['mean','median']).transpose().plot(kind='bar')
```

which will generate something like this:

[image]